# swift 2 local alert for multiple dates in array

Tags: swift, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I have an array of nsdates and I want to create a notification for each of them to happen when the time matches the current times.

so far i have this

```
for item in stuffThree {

            print("test")

            var notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
            notification.category = "test1"
            notification.alertBody = "test2"
            notification.fireDate  = item
            print(item)

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

        }
```

As of now I am not getting anything. What i do is create a date a minute ahead and then let the clock tick down and wait and nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple suggestions:

1. Set `notification.alertBody = "Test"`
2. Call `localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()`
3. Check your outputs with `print(notification.fireDate)` and
   print(`notification`)
4. If in the simulator, you may not have the notification pop up if the app is open, so close it (shift+cmd+h)

Comment: that is def an improvement...before i was getting nothing. Now however I am getting a notification every time the func gets called (i have the method on a timer that gets called every 5 seconds) Is there any way to have it keep running every 5 seconds (the func does other stuff too) and first check if the condition is met and THEN run the alert?

Comment: Sure - set up an `if condition==true {}` wrapper around the notification scheduling function.

Comment: maybe im doing it wrong but I tried wrapping inside the for loop an if statement that is if ......if item == dateNow { ...}. now nothing runs... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to have a better condition check set up - in what instance do you want to create a new notification? For instance, `NSDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(previousTimeSent) > x`

Comment: ah I only want to create a notification if the nsdate inside of the array matches the current nsdate

Comment: i tried       let timeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(item)
            
            if timeInterval > 86400 {         but it sill runs every 5 seconds

Comment: Without seeing your code, I'd suggest printing out to the log each of these variables, because I think some have values different than you're expecting.

Comment: Yes i actually did that and even though i was converting the current date to the default date, when i scrolled several times on the date picker it would increment the days..so my notifications probably would have worked if i waited a day or so lol.....thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
```

You should read [This](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/21/2/scheduling-notifications-uilocalnotification) on HackingWithSwift. It should help you out.